# Segmentation fault (core dumped) Error Message during c++ code compilation

Tags: c++, linux

I am new to c++ and trying to compile the simple c++ programm. using vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#define BUFSIZE 100

using namespace std;

typedef struct AA{
    int a;
    std::string a_str;
}A;
typedef struct BB{
    int b;
    std::string b_str;
    vector<AA> Aobj;
}B;

int main()
{
  B bobj;
  bobj.Aobj[0].a=4;
  bobj.Aobj[0].a_str="DICOM";
  bobj.b_str="LDAP";
  bobj.b_str="DICOM";
  size_t ipos;
  ipos=bobj.Aobj[0].a_str.find("COM");
  if(ipos!=string::npos)
        cout<<"String Found Successfully....";
  else
        cout<<"String Not Found ....";
  return 0;
}
```

when i compile the program it shows a error message
**Segmentation fault (core dumped)** 
using Ubuntu OS

Comment: Compilers should not break in such a fashion:(

Comment: Are you sure it is the *compiler* (i.e. `g++`) that shows the message, not *running* your buggy program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is first create an object of type AA and then push it to the vector of B as

```
AA aa;
aa.a = 4;
aa.a_str = "hello world";
bobj.Aobj.push_back(aa);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a constructor for `B`. Also C++ doesn't need struct typedefs like this. Simply

```
struct B {
    int b;
    std::string b_str;
    std::vector<A> Aobj;

    B() : Aobj(std::vector<A>(1)) {}
};
```